# Grab the value of Bootstrap slider in php?

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code. I am using bootstrap for a slider input.

```
<input type="text" class="slider slider-primary" id="slider5" value="" name="question_five" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-value="5"  data-slider-selection = "before"  data-slider-handle="round">
```

*How can I get the default value using post method?*
I tried placing the `value="5"` but it doesn't show any value at all.

*Any idea of grabbing the value in php?*

Comment: what exactly you want ? where is the slider bootstrap code?

Comment: I want to get the default value of the slide when no one slides it.

Comment: @яша  it is a range type slider. But wondering why bootstrap used "text" type

Comment: see this data-slider-value="5"  -- I am trying to echo this value after from submission if the slider is not moved.

Comment: are you sure the $_POST["question_five"] does not echo it after posting ?

Comment: yes, this is not echoing value. p.s: I am talking about the default value. I can of course grab the value if user moves the slide

Answer (score 0):

Check This documentation for bootstrap slider http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/

`$('#ex1').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return value
    }
});`